# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' when go load

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have the red line error in the final code line how can I resolve the problem of the string. I'm supposed to overload the load or what can I do to put the string I need "matematicas"

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SantillanaWindows8.Books.BookModels.ImageContent>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, int)' has some invalid arguments.
```

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Code:

```
string matematicas = "";
            for (int x = 1; x < lstCurrentPageImages.Count(); x++)
            {
                matematicas = "\n" + matematicas + "Ǣæȹms" + lstCurrentPageImages.ElementAt(x).ImgUri + "Ǣǣȹ";
            }
            rchPopUpContestaTemplate.Blocks.Clear();
            rchPopUpContestaTemplate.Blocks.Add(parser.ParseParaCrecer(matematicas, currentPageSettings.Materia, currentFontSize, Colors.Black, new FontFamily("Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias")));
            scrollMathAperturaContent.DataContext = lstCurrentPageBookExercises.ElementAt(1);
            InsertImagesIntoContent(stckContentAperturaMath);
            LoadExcersicePopupBox(lstCurrentPageImages.ElementAt(matematicas));   <----//Red line error is here
```

Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int':

```
LoadExcersicePopupBox(lstCurrentPageImages.ElementAt(matematicas));   <----//Red line error is here
```

Comment: ugh, another...  SHOW WHAT IS NOT CONVERTING TO INT!!!!!

Comment: I said the final line... there is the error.... I cant put ElementAt(matematicas) cuz matematicas is a string....

Comment: Put a breakpoint so that you can tell what the value of `matematicas` is.  Then you'll know why it can't be converted to an `int`

Comment: what exactly are you expecting us to tell you here?

Comment: matematicas has to be a integer not a random string that you generate.

Answer (score 4):

`ElementAt()` expects a NUMBER

```
string matematicas = "";   <--- you declared STRING
matematicas = "\n" + matematicas + "Ǣæȹms" + lstCurrentPageImages.ElementAt(x).ImgUri + "Ǣǣȹ";
```

your variable matematicas looks like string.

```
LoadExcersicePopupBox(lstCurrentPageImages.ElementAt(matematicas));   <--- using ElementAt with a STRING
```

IT WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: All you telling me I already know... but its ok I fix it.

Comment: if you know it then why are you posting code without showing the VALUE of that is failed.  What else would I answer without knowing the value????